# Creating a Linux "sandbox" with AppArmor

Tags: linux, apparmor

I'm trying to sandbox a particular Python process, giving it access only to network communications and a select number of files on the file system. I followed the directions on [the Ubuntu community docs site](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.10/serverguide/C/apparmor.html) and the Chromium project's [article on their sandboxing](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxSandboxing).

However, I only want to block some Python processes. To get aroundt this, I've symlinked the Python executable to another location (call it `python sandbox`) and applied an AppArmor profile to it.

When I launch `python-sandbox`, I am still able to open arbitrary files on the filesystem and read from them. What's wrong?
I've done the following:

Created an AppArmor profile as follows:

```
#include <tunables/global>
/opt/python-sandbox {
    #include <abstractions/base>
    #include <abstractions/fonts>
    /proc/** r,
    /usr/lib/python2.7/** r,
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/** r,
    network,
}
```

Copied it into the `/etc/apparmor.d/` directory with the name `opt.python-sandbox` (since the symlink is to `/opt/python-sandbox`.

Run `apparmor_parser /etc/apparmor.d/opt.python-sandbox`.

Did I do something wrong? Should I consider another approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aha! I missed something. Apparently it's known that AppArmor doesn't work on symlinks in general. Copying the Python executable over to /opt/python-sandbox worked fine.